# Return rows which matches CSV column to CSV search string?

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a database table, that has column which stores comma separated string values.
Say for example

```
Row   CSVColumn
1.    value1, value2
2.    value1, value3
3.    value2, value4
```

My search parameter is again comma separated say value2, value4

Now I want to return all those rows which matches search parameter. In this example should return Row 1 and Row 3.

Can somebody help in writing MS SQL query for this?

Comment: It would be better to fix your data model, if possible. Multiple values belong in multiple rows, not crammed together into a string which SQL Server has no knowledge of the contents of.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't think I can fix data model. That's my constraint and requirement!

Comment: why you don't return Row1 for your given example?

Comment: @Darka Oops, my typo. Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: how many data are in this table? I think about split table CSVColumn into rows and then look up.

Comment: @Darka I believe data won't be more than 100 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How About this example. I am splitting string into rows for Search string and for CSVColumn.

After that I just INNER JOIN them.

I am using xml for splitting but you also can create function for this.

```
DECLARE @CsvTable TABLE (Rowid INT, CsvColumn VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @CsvTable SELECT '1', 'value1'
INSERT INTO @CsvTable SELECT '2', 'value1, value3'
INSERT INTO @CsvTable SELECT '3', 'value2, value4'

DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(20) = 'value2, value3' 

;WITH SearchTable AS (
    SELECT LTRIM(O.splitdata) AS Searchdata
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST('<X>'+replace(@SearchText,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS XmlData
        ) AS xT
     CROSS APPLY
     ( 
         SELECT xdata.D.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS splitdata 
         FROM xT.XmlData.nodes('X') as xdata(D)
     ) O
), SplitTable AS (

    SELECT xT.Rowid,
     LTRIM(O.splitdata) AS splitdata
    FROM (
        SELECT T.Rowid, CAST('<X>'+replace(T.CsvColumn,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS XmlData
        FROM @CsvTable AS T
        ) AS xT
     CROSS APPLY
     ( 
         SELECT xdata.D.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS splitdata 
         FROM xT.XmlData.nodes('X') as xdata(D)
     ) O

)
SELECT DISTINCT CT.*
FROM @CsvTable AS CT
INNER JOIN SplitTable AS SplitT 
    ON SplitT.RowID = CT.RowID
INNER JOIN SearchTable AS SrchT
    ON SrchT.Searchdata = SplitT.splitdata
```